# while loop on bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell-script

My code is :

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

    COUNTER=$((COUNTER +1))     
    echo $COUNTER

    if (($COUNTER%3 == 0));  then
        echo "Counter now is 3"
        sleep 2
    fi

    if (($COUNTER%6 == 0));  then
        echo "Counter now is 6"
        sleep 2
    fi

    if (($COUNTER%9 == 0));  then
        echo "Counter now is 9"
        sleep 2
    fi

    if (($COUNTER%12 == 0));  then
        echo "Counter now is 12"
        sleep 2
    fi

    if (($COUNTER%15 == 0));  then
        echo "Counter now is 15"
        sleep 2
        exit
    fi

done
```

and my output is :

```
./test2.sh 
1
2
3
Counter now is 3
4
5
6
Counter now is 3
Counter now is 6
7
8
9
Counter now is 3
Counter now is 9
10
11
12
Counter now is 3
Counter now is 6
Counter now is 12
13
14
15
Counter now is 3
Counter now is 15
```

Why is it showing, every time, `Counter now is 3` or sometime show more on `echo`. I don't want it to show additional on `echo`

Comment: Because `6`,`9`,`12` and `15` are also multiples of `3`

Comment: ... if you want to make it work in the intended way, then re-order the conditions so that you test from largest modulus to smallest and add a `continue` statement at the bottom of each test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more correct if your outputs said what the corresponding test tested for, e.g.

```
if (( COUNTER%3 == 0 )); then
    echo 'COUNTER is a multiple of 3'
fi
```

This is the test that you have, and if you think about it, 6, 9, 12, and 15 are also multiples of 3.

In this short script, I would suggest that you test directly on `COUNTER` rather than on `COUNTER%somevalue` if you want to check the actual value of the counter rather than whether it's a multiple of some value:

```
if (( COUNTER == 3 )); then
    echo 'COUNTER is 3'
fi
```

Note that `$` is not needed on variables when they are used in an arithmetic context.

Answer (score 0):

Because output is a lie.

- What is output when it says “count is…”?
- What would be a better text than “Count is”?
- Where does it `echo` count? (make it `echo` count is …)

When you have fixed that, you should understand what it is doing.